# Unhandle Promise rejection inside try block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I'm having difficulties understanding why the code below throws an *Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning* :

```
router.post('/stampaClasse/:as(20[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9])/:classe([1-8])',async function (req,res,next){

  const sezioni = await Classi.getSezioniFromAnnoScolasticoAndClasse(req.params.as,req.params.classe);
  let options = {
    semestre: req.body.semestre,
    fontSize: req.body.fontSize,
    textColor: '#515151',
    gridColor: '#bec0be',
    corDidattico:{
      titolo:'prof.',
      nome:'Roberto',
      cognome:'Dalema'
    }
  }
  let newPDF = new pdfKit();
  try{
    for(sezione of sezioni){

      const idStudentiPromise = Classi.getStudentiFromAnnoScolasticoAndClasseAndSezione(req.params.as,req.params.classe,sezione)
      const materiePromise = Classi.getMaterieSezione(req.params.as,req.params.classe,sezione)
      const infoStudentiPromise = Promise.all(  Studenti.getInfoStudentiById(await idStudentiResults) )


      let classe = {
        annoScolastico: req.params.as,
        classe : req.params.classe,
        sezione: sezione,
        materie: await materiePromise,
        studenti: await infoStudentiPromise
      }
      for(studente of classe.studenti){
        studente.pagelleMateriePromises = classe.materie.map(async m=>Pagelle.getPagellaFromStudente(classe.annoScolastico,classe.classe,classe.sezione,m,studente.id));
      }
      for(studente of classe.studenti){
        studente.pagelleMaterie = await Promise.all(studente.pagelleMateriePromises)
        addHeader(newPDF,studente,classe,options);
        addPagelleSemestre(newPDF,studente,classe,options);
        addFooter(newPDF,studente,classe,options);
      }
    }

    newPDF.pipe(res);
    newPDF.end();
  }
  catch(err){
    next(err)
  }
});
```

The error occurs multiple times, and it is caused by the fact that at line

```
const infoStudentiPromise = Promise.all(  Studenti.getInfoStudentiById(await idStudentiResults) )
```

idStudentiResults alredy returns a Promise.all()

**regardles** of what is causing the error i'd like to know why it says the error is not beeing handled. Is the try catch not enaugh?

Comment: Promise.all takes an array of promises and resolves them in a then block.
Check out this, it might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I'd also check out [Jon Skeet's question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) and [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: You've *said* `Module.getInfo(ids)` returns a promise, not an array. If that's true (*showing* us would be much better), then why are you passing it into `Promise.all`?  That would seem to serve no purpose...

Comment: `why it is saying the error is unhandled`  because the error is unhanded.  A normal `try / catch` is not able to catch a promise error, unless you used `async / awat`, and did `await Promise.all()`

Comment: Why are you wrapping a promise with a promise

Comment: @KevinB Because the service exposing the find dosen't support promises

Comment: I mean... it sure does appear to, it's a thenable.

Comment: @KevinB Ye I know, but mongoose documentation says that the are not really promises... i dont really know

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` needs to receive an array of promises as param. Make sure that `Module.getInfo(ids)` is returning that.

Comment: Maybe share the code for `Module.getInfo` and tell us what exactly is that you're trying to achieve

Comment: I know where the error lies, what i don't know is why it is saying the error is unhandled

Comment: This line doesn't have a catch for the promises: `const infoPromise = Promise.all(  Module.getInfo(ids) );`

Comment: Do you mean i need a try-catch block for every line of code if that code execute some asyncronous operation?

Comment: @FilippoBosco Not a try-catch block but the `.catch` method for Promises